# Styling and Validations in ActiveStorage Rails like Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, rails-activestorage

I am using Active Storage for the first time, in my new project, before that I used  Paperclip. In paperclip, we had option to add default styles and validations for content type. like:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

I cannot seem to find any documentation for how to implement these functionalities in ActiveStorage.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations

Answer (score 2):

There's no validation in ActiveStorage yet, so you could use [custom validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) like this:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :some_img
  validates :some_img, image: true
end


class ImageValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << I18n.t('errors.file_size') unless file_size_valid?(value)
    record.errors[attribute] << I18n.t('errors.file_type') unless file_type_valid?(value)
  end

  private

  def file_size_valid?(value)
    value.blob.byte_size <= 5.megabytes
  end

  def file_type_valid?(value)
    !value.blob.content_type.starts_with?('image/')
  end
end
```

There's no paperclip-like syntax for styling, but you could use [variant](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images) for this purpose:

```
my_object.some_img.variant(resize: '100x100>')
```

It passes [options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize) directly to ImageMagick.

Also there's no default image option, so it may be helpful to create some sort of method in the model, or as decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Add this to gemfile

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

Then bundle install

## config/environments/production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

Additionally, we’ll need to the set the AWS configuration variables on the Heroku application.

```
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
heroku config:set AWS_REGION=your_aws_region

$ rails g migration AddAvatarToProfiles

class AddAvatarToProfiless < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :profiles, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :profiles, :avatar
  end
end
```

Then `rake db:migrate`

This is in the view

```
<%= form_for(@profile, multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Make a friend' %>
    <%= link_to 'Nevermind', friends_path, class: 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and this is inside the controller

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  # Other CRUD actions omitted

```
 def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    if @profile.save
      redirect_to @friend, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.'
     else
       render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:avatar, :name)
  end
end
```

Comment: You just gave me guide for integrating paperclip with my app. I don't need paperclip. I want to integrate ActiveStorage in my app and have same functionalities like we have in Paperclip.

Comment: yeah by adding something like this rails g migration AddAvatarToProfiles